# Using Headless Mode With Chrome Less Effective?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium + beautiful soup (using selenium to open pages with a lot of javascript and using a javascript command to turn it into a BeautifulSoup object)  to scrape data from sports websites, but for some reason I cannot use a headless browser.  When I do implement a headless browser with chromedriver, I don't scrape nearly as much data as when I let chromedriver open and run.  Has anyone had a similar issue or does anyone have any suggestions?

```
    def get_bs(self, url, sport_url):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='drivers/chromedriver')
        driver.get(url + sport_url)
        time.sleep(3)

        site = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
        driver.close()
        return BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')
```

My project is extremely long and consists of multiple files.  But, above is the function I use to access a website and convert the site into a BeautifulSoup object, which I then scrape in another function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very easy for a website to detect you are using automation with Chrome via the `navigator.webdriver` javascript variable. Depending on the version of Chrome you are using, this will only be true in headless mode. In more recent versions they have patched this (and the variable is always set when using selenium).

After navigating to the webpage try running:

```
print(driver.execute_script("return window.navigator.webdriver"))
```

If this returns True, you are likely being limited/blocked.

Comment: What were the results of your test? Is the variable set on both runs (headless and not)?

Comment: They were both "True" regardless of whether it was in headless mode or full web browser.

Comment: That is likely not your problem then. Make sure you adjust the size of the browser as well.